# Ionic 2 importJsonToDb() escape characters

Tags: json, sqlite, cordova, ionic2, escaping

I'm trying to bulk-import some JSON-Data with the cordova-sqlite-porter into a Database of an Ionic 2 App. It works almost fine but I can't escape the characters `'` and `"`. Here is a JSON I want to import:

```
let sqlJsonBlock = '{"data":{"inserts":{'
    + '"TABLENAME":[{'
        + '"LABEL":"Here are some "Characters"",'
        + '"ID":11,'
        + '"NUMBER":"0004"'
    + '}]'
+ '}}};'

this.sqliteporter.importJsonToDb( db, JSON.parse(sqlJsonBlock) );
```

So the word *Characters* should be imported with quotes but won't. I tried double-escaping the Characters like `""Characters""` or with leading Slashes like `\"Characters\"` or both `\"\"Characters\"\"` `\\\"Characters\\\"` but nothing seems to work.

Does anybody know how to escape these Characters in JSON for importing them into a SQLite-DB?

**EDIT:**

I wrapped the test-data in some real JSON-Object and successfully imported it but then the escape-characters are also imported into the DB. So after selecting the data again, i get a string like `Here are some \"Characters\"`. So this don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [complex_dump.json](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example/blob/master/www/json/complex_dump.json) in the [example project](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-sqlite-porter-example) for the plugin, you'll see some examples of how the plugin expects quotes (and other special charaters) to be escaped in the JSON structure, for example:

```
"Title": "Up An' Atom",
"Composer": "Enotris Johnson/Little Richard/Robert \"Bumps\" Blackwell",
"Name": "Cavalleria Rusticana \\ Act \\ Intermezzo Sinfonico",
```

So, in your example it should be:

```
let sqlJsonBlock = '{"data":{"inserts":{'
    + '"TABLENAME":[{'
        + '"LABEL":"Here are some \"Characters\"",'
        + '"ID":11,'
        + '"NUMBER":"0004"'
    + '}]'
+ '}}};'

this.sqliteporter.importJsonToDb( db, sqlJsonBlock);
```

Note: you don't need to parse the JSON string as the plugin will do it for you.

But it would be easier to just define a JSON object literal:

```
let sqlJsonBlock = {
    "data":{
        "inserts":{
            "TABLENAME":[{
                "LABEL":"Here are some \"Characters\"",
                "ID":11,
                "NUMBER":"0004"
            }]
        }
    }
};

this.sqliteporter.importJsonToDb( db, sqlJsonBlock);
```

Comment: I really tried that but it doesn't work. The data gets imported without escaped quotes and when I add the quotes as you mentioned nothing happens. Not even an error is reported. Single-quotes `'` can be escaped this way but the double-quotes won't.